# Drilling holes in crawl space block foundation

Tags: concrete, foundation, crawlspace, cinderblock

I did a crawl space encapsulation myself. I used foundation pins to secure the vapor barrier to the walls every 16". Unfortunately, my walls were so wet I couldn't use a butyl tape like the manufacturer recommended. So I only did the foundation pins and then I plan to go back and use the polyurethane caulk as they recommended to completely seal the vapor barrier to the wall. To help keep the barrier sealed to the wall with the caulk longer, I was going to put extra foundation pins in. So have a pin every 8" instead of 16" (basically two per block instead of one). I think this will help the seal last a bit longer as there will be smaller gaps between each pin.

Now to my question. I'm 99% sure drilling a 1/4" hole in my block foundation wall every 8" won't hurt anything, but I wanted to be completely sure before I do it. Just want to make sure there is no obscure building code or something I'm overlooking that might be flagged when we try to sell the house. I've already drilled holes every 16". So those are already there. I also have holes for the foam insulation boards I put up. Those foam boards are secured with fasteners as well, but the boards are 8' long and I only used 6 fasteners per board. So not too many holes for that. Lastly, there are already weep holes at the very bottom block above the footer. There is a hole for each cell in the block. The blocks have 3 cells (instead of the normal 2), so there is a small hole for each one there at the bottom.

It just sort of feels like a lot of holes which is making me second guess things.

[image]

Comment: You're fine.  One of the standard methods for termite treatment is to do just what you've done - drill a hole into each hollow core of the block, and inject insecticide into the block.